# Can we use github repository as an artifact while creating maven project?

Tags: java, maven, github, archetypes

I've implemented a maven library and published it to GitHub. Now I wanted to use this repository as an archetype to create another maven project `(without maven central repo)` like below

[image]

When I tried this it's giving the below error

[image]

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I haven't worked with them, but I think that GitHub packages can support this. See https://github.com/features/packages and https://docs.github.com/en/packages/learn-github-packages/introduction-to-github-packages.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have a git repo which defines 'archetype' project and then package and install it's generated artifact into the github hosted artifact repository.

See this maven guide to define the archrtype

- https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html

And use github actions to publish the artifact.

Comment: `mvn deploy -Dregistry=https://maven.pkg.github.com/yourusername -Dtoken=your_token` is this the command to install artifact into the github hosted artifact repository?

Comment: I created the archetype and published into github repo, but still facing the same issue. How to install artifact into github hosted artifact repository?

Comment: What have you tried, what error do you get. I'd suggest you read https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-apache-maven-registry